# How did Nora return from the Underworld despite being left there by Yato?

Tags: noragami

I'm wondering how Nora got back from the Underworld despite being left there by Yato (Noragami Aragoto Episode 12-13).

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That scene was not there in the manga. It is not clear from the manga if she was left in the Underworld. It was shown that she was found outside in the grass and was revived by 'father' (don't want to spoil by telling his name).

[image]

[image]

[image]